# about the C++ dynamic cast with template class

Tags: c++, templates, dynamic, casting

I have base class A, class B inherits from A, class C which is a template class inherits from A. class D inherits from C.  The relation is as follows:

```
        A
       / \   
      B   C (template class)
           \
            D
```

I can create an A object O1 using D object D1, then I want to dynamic cast O1 to a type C object C1.
But I find it fails. My question is why this process fails?

Then I use static_cast to create C type object C2 from D object D1, and I checked C2 has right value from D2. Is it always successful to convert from D type to C type using static_cast?

Thank you!!!

Comment: Post complete code, along with expected and actual results. There are an infinite number of things that could be going wrong, and we can't tell which one it is without specific code.

Comment: Does your base class have any virtual functions? If not, you can't use `dynamic_cast`.

Comment: Bear in mind that most these conversions are only valid for pointers and references, not for the objects themselves. It's not clear from your description exactly what you're trying to convert; some example code would be helpful.

Answer (score 16):

Well, since `C` is a template, it isn’t a type and cannot be used as a target of a cast (neither dynamic to static), and you cannot derive from it. You need to *instantiate* the class template. The resulting class *can* be used in a cast. That is, the following will work:

```
struct A { };
template <typename T> struct C : A { };
struct D : C<int> { };

D d;
A& a = d;
C<int>& c = static_cast<C<int>&>(a); // or dynamic_cast, if `A` were polymorphic
```

Comment: @IceCool Correct, I added a clarification.

Comment: If you have `error C2683: 'dynamic_cast' : '...' is not a polymorphic type` just add a *virtual destructor* to base class: `virtual ~A() { }`

Answer (score 9):

> to a type C object C1. But I find it fails.

Since `C` is a template, there really is no "type C". Rather there is `C<int>` or `C<Foo>` (assuming you have one template argument). Templates only become classes when they are specialized.

So if D inherited from a specific type of C:

```
 class D : public C<int>
 {
 };
```

You could `dynamic_cast` up to a `C<int>` but not to say a `C<float>`.

To help better explain, your inheritance tree is really

```
         A
       / | \
C<float>... C<int> 
             | 
             D
```

So C isn't a parent of D, but `C<int>` is (in this example). Instances of `C` don't really exist in runtime, it's only instances fully specified of `C<type>` that actually exist.

Comment: Not just runtime -- `C` isn't a type, period.